# Why do I get a syntax error with "Sinatra: Up and Running" game.rb "Rock Paper Scissors"?

Tags: ruby, hash, sinatra

I'm following this example from "Sinatra: Up and Running", and I get the following error message:

> game.rb:8: odd number list for Hash
>       @defeat = { rock:  :scissors, paper:  :rock, scissors:  :paper }
>                                   ^
>   game.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
>       @defeat = { rock:  :scissors, paper:  :rock, scissors:  :paper }
>                                   ^

after running:

```
$ ruby -rubygems game.rb
```

However, I have no idea why it has trouble with this statement. I copied the code straight from the book. I've tried many variations and nothing seems to work. This code is suppose to output "Ouch rock beats scissors. Better luck next time!" if I go to localhost:4567/throw/scissors and the computer chooses rock.

game.rb below

```
require 'sinatra'

# before we process a route, we'll set the response as
# plain text and set up an array of viable moves that
# a player (and the computer) can perform
before do
  content_type :txt
  @defeat = {rock: :scissors, paper: :rock, scissors: :paper}
  @throws = @defeat.keys
end

get '/throw/:type' do
  # the params[] hash stores querystring and form data.
  player_throw = params[:type].to_sym

  # in the case of a player providing a throw that is not valid,
  # we halt with a status code of 403 (Forbidden) and let them
  # know they need to make a valid throw to play.
  if !@throws.include?(player_throw)
    halt 403, "You must throw one of the following: #{@throws}"
  end

  # now we can select a random throw for the computer
  computer_throw = @throws.sample

  # compare the player and computer throws to determine a winner
  if player_throw == computer_throw
    "You tied with the computer. Try again!"
  elsif computer_throw == @defeat[player_throw]
    "Nicely done; #{player_throw} beats #{computer_throw}!"
  else
    "Ouch; #{computer_throw} beats #{player_throw}. Better luck next time!"
  end
end
```

By the way the code I used for the original question was actually one of the "fixes" I tried not the actual book code. Apparently the book code had the same thing sczizzo suggested. However, I'm still getting an error (see above). Anyway if I try sczizzo alternative:

> {  :rock  => :scissors, :paper => :rock, :scissors => :paper  }

then game.rb compiles, but I get a runtime error:

> #<NoMethodError: undefined method `sample' for [:rock, :scissors, :paper]:Array>

if I visit http://localhost:4567/throw/scissors

**Solution: Instal Ruby 1.9!**
**Thanks everyone**

Comment: I found [the page you're looking in Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=0aF5-u3H9SQC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=Sinatra:+Up+and+Running+game.rb&source=bl&ots=gqAgp5jELe&sig=mrnFcTYICniG5823NdjIpVq8KbA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tg79TuPhL4SKgwe26ZWsAg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), which confirms my answer. Maybe a misprint in your edition or your simply copied it down wrong.

Comment: Yes I originally tried what the book said and I got the above error. (See my updated post). Then I tried my way and I got the error message you saw me put up. Anyway, thanks for your alternative way of writing the hash. It compiles, but I seem to get a NoMethodError when I visit the page http://localhost:4567/throw/scissors.

Comment: What's the complete error? It may be unrelated to the hash syntax.

Comment: Are you using ruby 1.9 ? Both the new hash syntax and Array#sample are 1.9 only features.

Comment: NoMethodError - undefined method `sample' for [:rock, :scissors, :paper]:Array:
 game.rb:24:in `GET /throw/:type'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1211:in `call'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1211:in `compile!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `[]'

 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `route!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:788:in `route_eval'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `route!'

Comment: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:819:in `catch'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:819:in `process_route'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:771:in `route!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:770:in `each'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:770:in `route!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `dispatch!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `call!'

Comment: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `catch'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `call!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:692:in `call'

Comment: Oh I see. I think you're on Ruby 1.8, which has neither the new-style hashes, [nor `Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html). I recommend upgrading 1.9, as it's generally better and works with your book. I highly recommend using a tool like [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage Ruby installations on unix-like systems.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they meant `@defeat = { rock: :scissors, paper: :rock, scissors: :paper }`. Now, that's using a new-style Ruby hash, which might also be written like this: `{ :rock => :scissors, :paper => :rock, :scissors => :paper }`.

Answer (score 0):

The error explains where the problem is. If you paste the definition for `@defeat` into IRB:

```
1.9.2p290 :002 > @defeat = {rock :scissors, paper :rock, scissors :paper}
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
@defeat = {rock :scissors, paper :rock, scissors :paper}
                 ^
```

You can fix it by following the answer given by @sczizzo.

Comment: Frederich Cheung noticed I didn't have version 1.9 of Ruby. That was the issue. These hash operations are only supported in 1.9. I'm sure there is a 1.8 equivalent, but 1.9 did the trick.

Comment: I don't think there is a 1.8 equivalent. The use of the `=>` operator is hardwired if I remember right. You can use the "[backports](http://rubydoc.info/gems/backports/frames)" gem to get `Array.sample` in 1.8.7.